# Linux Daemon Stopping start-stop-daemon

Tags: linux, daemon, start-stop-daemon

I have a daemon I am creating in linux. I created the init.d file and have successfully started the daemon process using

```
/etc/init.d/mydaemon start
```

When I try to stop it(with /etc/init.d/mydaemon stop), however, it stops successfully, but start-stop-daemon never seems to complete as evidenced by no echos occuring immediately after the call to start-stop-daemon

Verbose mode shows that it stopped the process, and looking at system monitor, it does stop the process.

```
Stopped mydaemon (pid 13292 13310).
```

Here is my stop function of the init.d file.

```
do_stop()
{
    # Return
    #   0 if daemon has been stopped
    #   1 if daemon was already stopped
    #   2 if daemon could not be stopped
    #   other if a failure occurred
    start-stop-daemon --stop --name $NAME -v
echo "stopped"#This is never printed and the script never formally gives shell back.
    RETVAL="$?"

    [ "$RETVAL" = 2 ] && return 2

    # Wait for children to finish too if this is a daemon that forks
    # and if the daemon is only ever run from this initscript.
    # If the above conditions are not satisfied then add some other code
    # that waits for the process to drop all resources that could be
    # needed by services started subsequently.  A last resort is to
    # sleep for some time.
    start-stop-daemon --stop --quiet --oknodo --retry=0/30/KILL/5 --exec $DAEMON 
    [ "$?" = 2 ] && return 2
    # Many daemons don't delete their pidfiles when they exit.

    return "$RETVAL"
}
```

I am running this on virtual machine, does this affect anything?

Answer (score 0):

Running on a virtual machine shouldn't affect this.
And I have no idea why this is happening or how it is taking over control of the parent script.

However, I just encountered this issue and discovered that if I do:

> start-stop-daemon ... && echo -n

it will work as expected and relinquish control of the shell.

I have no idea why this works, but it seems to work.